# Custom template tag wont assign to {% with %} context

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm in need of a custom tag where multiple keyword arguments can be passed in for the purpose of creating an unique id for a given object instance. Whatever string the tag returns it assigns the string as a context variable to the included template. Yet the `id` context variable remains empty. In this case, the ids for the SVG elements only return the hardcoded strings `upvote_` and `downvote_`.

How can I fix this so that the `id` context variable is interpolated into the string of the SVG id attributes?

- An example being: `upvote_queston101`

```
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}
    {% include "./posted.html" with post=answer id=set_id question=question.id answer=answer.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

```
<div class="rating_box">
  <div class="vote">
    <svg id="upvote_{{ id }}" class="vote_button">

    </svg>
    <p>{{ post.score }}</p>
    <svg id="downvote_{{ id }}" class="vote_button">

    </svg>
  </div>
  <p class="post_body_content">{{ post.body }}</p>
</div>
```

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def set_id(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['question'] and kwargs['answer']:
        q_id, a_id = kwargs['question'], kwargs['answer']
        return f"question{q_id}_answer{a_id}"
    q_id = kwargs['question']
    return f"question{q_id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it more step-by-step and assign temp variable for ids. Suppose there is some conflict with inline usage of "=" signs

```
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}

    {% set_id question=question.id answer=answer.id as ids %}
    {% include "./posted.html" with post=answer id=ids  %}

{% endfor %}
```